# How to use specific version of amphtml?

Tags: html, amp-html

currently I am using amp script from `https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js`. I believe this file contains latest release always. 
Recently my amp site is breaking, so i want to test with previous releases of amp html.

is there a way to to include specific version of amp html ??

Comment: Browsing their documentation, I wasn't able to find any way to link specific version. Try checking/ posting an [issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues) in their GitHub to get their official statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access specific versions of the AMP runtime via:

`https://cdn.ampproject.org/rtv/${VERSION}/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js`

Where `${VERSION}` is the current version number, e.g.: `1809142227020` preceded by `01` for the release version and `00` for the canary version.

For example, the current released version is:

`https://cdn.ampproject.org/rtv/011809142227020/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js`

and the current canary version is:

`https://cdn.ampproject.org/rtv/001809142227020/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a version of the AMP library somewhere and point your page to that, but this will only work for local testing.